# How to check the response from an Observable and display alerts for different responses in Angular4 with Rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have this service:

```
         return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, bodyString, options)
                     .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                     .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'));
```

with the function: `auth(body: Object) : Observable<Response>`

And then I'm subscribing in the component:

```
this.loginService.auth(value).subscribe(
              result => {
                swal('Error', result, 'warning')
              },
              err => {
                  // Log errors if any
                  console.log(err);
              });
```

How can I handle the value of the `result` and where? I want to display it based on his different values. You cannot check in the subscribe with `if` and `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the value of the result returned in the subscription. I'm going to assume result is a simple string, but it could actually be anything. Check what’s being returned in your result object and see whats most appropriate.

```
this.loginService.auth(value).subscribe((result) => {

    if (result === 'ok') {
        // its all good
    }

    if (result === 'bad') {
        // its bad
    }

}, (err) => {
    // Log errors if any
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: that's the problem - the response is a json (or a string). If i check the result with if:`Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'Response' and 'string'.`